# i need xslt dynamic menu from this XML

Tags: xml, xslt

```
<xml>
  <HeaderMenu>
    <headerMenuId>1</headerMenuId>
    <headerMenuName>Enterprise</headerMenuName>
    <headerMenuSort>1</headerMenuSort>
    <subMenu>
      <subMenuId>1</subMenuId>
      <submenuname>Full fill ment </submenuname>
      <submenuDispayOrderId>1</submenuDispayOrderId>
      <PageSections>
        <pagesectionId>1</pagesectionId>
        <PageSecName>First Sub-Navigation</PageSecName>
        <PageSecDescription>Dummy</PageSecDescription>
        <PageSecDispayOrderId>1</PageSecDispayOrderId>
      </PageSections> 
    </subMenu> 
 </HeaderMenu> 
</xml>
```

I need xslt dynamic menu and sub menus from 2 levels from this XML.
I need output like this here:

```
Enterprise
  ->Full fill ment 
             ->First Sub-Navigation
```

Comment: try this example: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/6452/XML-XSLT-Dynamic-Menu-with-ASP-NET

Comment: i did like this but i need templete method 
  <!-- LEVEL 1 -->
        <xsl:for-each select="HeaderMenu">
          <xsl:sort select="headerMenuName" data-type="text"/>
          <xsl:value-of select="headerMenuName"/>
          <!-- LEVEL 2 -->
        <ul>  <xsl:for-each select="subMenu">
            <li> <xsl:value-of select="submenuname"/>
              <!--level-3-->
              <ul>  <xsl:for-each select="PageSections">
                  <li>  <xsl:value-of select="PageSecName"/>
                  </li>
                </xsl:for-each>
              </ul>

Answer (score 1):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:template match="/xml/HeaderMenu">
  <xsl:value-of select="headerMenuName" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="subMenu" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="subMenu">
  -> <xsl:value-of select="submenuname" />
  <xsl:apply-templates select="PageSections" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="PageSections">
    -> <xsl:value-of select="PageSecName" />
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

XSLT is a declarative language: you don't have to use conditions or loops. Always try to use `apply-templates` instead of `xsl:for-each` and xpath conditions instead of `xsl:if`.
Please note that this becomes very powerful if your XML file structure is recursive. Your code will be very general and very short.

Comment: If you consider this as "the" answer, don't forget to "accept" it ;)